# Use GeckoView in react native

Tags: react-native, webview, geckoview

I'm working on a react native project that requires GeckoView as the browser for the WebView. However, since it's a native android library I'm not sure if I can use it in react native.

Is there any way to integrate Geckoview to a react native project or is there any possible alternative for this situation?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you try React Native WebView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate it. Take a look at [sunnylqm/react-native-geckoview](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-geckoview).

Be sure to look and run the Example provided in the ./example directory. (Saved me lots of time)

This is a very basic implementation that I only used as a model.

It was done in Java. If you need the Kotlin version I can provide that too.

Good Luck!